# How to get the number of likes for a post on Facebook using Python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-comments

I try to get the number of likes and comments to a post on the Facebook page of an organization. I have the Python codes for the count of shares work just fine, but not for likes and comments. Any suggestion?

```
import urllib
import json
import sys
import os

accessToken = 'TOKENVALUE'  #INSERT YOUR ACCESS TOKEN
userId = sys.argv[1]          
limit=100

# Read my likes as a json object
url='https://graph.facebook.com/'+userId+'/posts?access_token='+accessToken +'&limit='+str(limit)
data = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
id=0

print str(id)

for item in data['data']:
time=item['created_time'][11:19]
date=item['created_time'][5:10]
year=item['created_time'][0:4]
if 'shares' in item:
    num_share=item['shares']['count']
else:
    num_share=0
if 'likes' in item:
            num_like=item['likes']['count']
else:
            num_like=0


id+=1

print str(id)+'\t'+ time.encode('utf-8')+'\t'+date.encode('utf-8')+'\t'+year.encode('utf-8')+'\t'+ str(num_share)+'\t'+str(num_like)
```

Answer (score 3):

For getting likes and comments on a post, you would need to make separate call per post. These calls will give you the desired results. (look at the 'summary' field in the JSON response)

/{POST_ID}/likes?summary=1

/{POST_ID}/comments?summary=1

Ofcourse you will need to add your access token and all that.